# Android studio how to remove lines in build method in flutter

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter

I just updated flutter plugin and now I am having lines in the `build()` method, how can I remove these lines (vertical lines which start from `r` of `return` and `c` of `child`)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those lines are UI Guides.

To disable them `Settings` -> `Flutter` -> **Uncheck** `UI Guides`

### [image: options]

But you can have the UI Guides as well as the widget labels as shown

Check UI Guides option and uncheck Hide closing labels.

[image: UI guides + comments]